# How do you determine which element is the paused element in your process builder?

Tags: process-builder, flow-interviews

I have an advanced process builder that i'm working with.

I was under the impression that each criteria and action are 'elements' in the process builder that determines the element that get's paused

i.e. myWait_myRule_31.

In other words the total Criteria nodes + the total actions leading to your paused element would equal N.

However, it doesn't seem that this is the case based on my counting. Does anyone know of a way to determine the node that is paused by counting the nodes in the Process builder?

### update

The only way I can get the number to work out is if I can't Immediate actions in between the Criteria node, and the scheduled actions. It would appear that Salesforce counts these 'elements' even though they lack any 'immediate actions' this image below would mean that the scheduled action would be myWait_myRule_5...**I think**

[image]

Comment: The only way I can get the number to work out is if I can't Immediate actions in between the Criteria node, and the scheduled actions. It would appear that Salesforce counts these 'elements' even though they lack any 'immediate actions'